# Git: Push file doesn't show up on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I pushed a file to GitHub but it didn't show up.

```
$ git push -u origin master
Everything up-to-date
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
```

See my GitHub, it shows the following message:

```
 master had recent pushes 40 minutes ago
```

[image]

It should be a file like so:
[image]

Can someone help me, I'm new to GitHub.

Comment: Have you commited the changes before the push? What does `git status` say?

Comment: The first screenshot is displaying your main branch. You have to merge master into main.

Comment: $ git push -u origin master
Enumerating objects: 612, done.
Counting objects: 100% (612/612), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (592/592), done.
Writing objects: 100% (612/612), 35.84 MiB | 635.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 612 (delta 212), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (212/212), done.
remote:

 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default branch on Git and GitHub is now called **main**.

See the note below from this link: https://github.com/github/renaming

> Many communities, both on GitHub and in the wider Git community, are considering renaming the default branch name of their repository from master. GitHub is gradually renaming the default branch of our own repositories from master to main. We're committed to making the renaming process as seamless as possible for project maintainers and all of their contributors. This repository is our up-to-date guidance on how and when to rename your default branch.

The first screenshot shows the `main` branch and a message to create a pull request and merge the master branch into main, in green, right above it.

You have a few options:

**1 - Either work with `main` from the beginning**

When you create a git repository, the default branch is now called `main`. After committing to this branch, simply.

```
git push -u origin main
```

**2 - Remotely merge `master` into `main`, delete `master`**

Simply by clicking the GitHub suggested Pull Request message and following the instructions.

**3 - Locally merge `master` into `main`, delete `master` :**

Merge `master` into `main`

```
git checkout main
git merge master
git push origin main
```

Delete `master` both locally and remotely

```
git branch -d master
git push origin --delete master
```

**Verify**

To list the local and remote branches and their state:

```
git branch -avv
```

**Notice**

Make sure the `main` branch is up to date before pushing, so consider a `git pull` and fixing any conflicts as needed before pushing changes.

Comment: $ git push -u origin main
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/dwirput/skripsi.git'

Comment: $ git push -u origin main
To https://github.com/dwirput/skripsi.git
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/dwirput/skripsi.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: okay fixed by using git push -u origin main --force

Comment: @Rin Glad you fixed it. Just keep in mind that --force will overwrite the remote repository so use it with care. You can always create sample repo on GitHub to try out these commands without side-effects to real projects. Also just enlisted a few options to solve your immediate problem. There are even more ways to fix it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you want to try and push it to "origin main" instead of "origin master"

Comment: what different bewtween main and master? should i run git push -u origin main?

Comment: yes, github changed master branch to main branch because it was not politically correct